# Prove that a sequence convereges in the standard euclidean metric if and only if it converges in the Taxicab metric (for $\mathbb R^n$)

Tags: general-topology, limits, metric-spaces

4. Consider a function $d : \mathbb R^n\times\mathbb R^n \to\mathbb R$

$$(x, y) = |x_1 − y_1| + |x_2 − y_2| + \cdots + |x_n − y_n|.$$

Prove that a sequence $(x_k)$ converges to a limit $x$ in metric $d$ if and only if it converges to $x$ in the standard Euclidean metric $(d)$. Prove that a set $A \subseteq \mathbb R^n$ is open in the metric $d_0$ if and only if it is open in the standard Euclidean metric.

Comment: What have you done so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Generally questions posted here should not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is open in the standard Euclidean metric, then for every point $x\in A$ there is some number $\varepsilon>0$ such that the open ball of Euclidean radius $\varepsilon$ about $x$ is a subset of $A$.  If you can show that the ball of radius $\varepsilon$ in the other metric is a subset of the ball of Euclidean radius $\varepsilon$, then you can conclude that there is a ball of radius $\varepsilon$ in the other metric that is a subset of $A$, so $A$ is open in the other metric.

For the converse, a ball of radius $\varepsilon$ in the other matric should include as a subset a bull of Euclidean radius $\varepsilon/\sqrt n$.

Once you've done all that, you should be able to use that to prove the result about convergence of sequences.